# better than a cursor tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

The question here is simple (although I am prepared for the answer not to be), how can I make this query more efficient.

In a nutshell it copies records.  It selects X records, then using those records data duplicates them capturing the new identifier.  Using the id of the original record and new record, it then inserts by copying data of the original data for another table using the new identifier.

This takes a long time. Can you help shorten it?

```
DECLARE DaysToDuplicateCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT 
    DayId 
FROM [Days] 
WHERE AgentId IN ('XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX') 
AND PersonAgentId IN (
     'YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY'
    ,'WWWWWWWW-WWWW-WWWW-WWWW-WWWWWWWWWWWW'
    ,'ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    ,'TTTTTTTT-TTTT-TTTT-TTTT-TTTTTTTTTTTT'
)

DECLARE @Id INT

OPEN DaysToDuplicateCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM DaysToDuplicateCursor INTO @Id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        --
        -- Insert Days data.
        --
        INSERT INTO [Days] (
               [DayTemplateId]
              ,[DayDate]
        )
        SELECT [DayTemplateId]
              ,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,[DayDate]) AS [DayDate]
          FROM [Days] WHERE [DayId] = @Id
        --
        -- Insert Periods data.
        --
        INSERT INTO [Periods] (
           [DayId]
          ,[PeriodTemplateId]
        )
        SELECT 
           SCOPE_IDENTITY()
          ,[PeriodTemplateId]
        FROM [Periods] WHERE [DayId] = @Id
        --
    END
CLOSE DaysToDuplicateCursor
DEALLOCATE DaysToDuplicateCursor
```

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: how much more efficient do you want it to be? Is the cursor itself slow? Are there any indexes on AgentId and/or PersonsAgentId? How many rows is all involved tables?

Comment: The missing `FETCH NEXT FROM DaysToDuplicateCursor INTO @Id` before the `END` keyword of the `WHILE... BEGIN` block caused the speed issue.  That is, the TSQL is incorrect in my original example and I failed to notice until after posting.  Once amended (including the addition mentioned here) the query ran in the expected milliseconds.  Thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a cursor at all if you use the OUTPUT clause instead of asking for scope_identity. You will put this information into a table varaiable. You will also want to return any other columns in the output clause that uniquely identify the record so you can use them in joins to get the data you need in subsequent inserts.

Comment: This is not an answer - you haven't looked at the query long enough. It is not so trivial because there is a correlation between the 2 inserts. The @id used in the 2nd insert cannot easily be derived from the 1st using OUTPUT.

Comment: If you add another column to the table, you can insert id1 into the id2 row. At that point I think you can use OUTPUT to export the two values for the newly-inserted row; one for id1, then id2.

Failing that, you now have rows where you know a) that the row was just created by your process and b) which row was the original for that process.